# Does dm-crypt utilize multiple cores? (Interested in multi-core Pi clones)

Tags: raspberry-pi, performance, cpu, dm-crypt

I'm considering replacing single-core Raspberry Pi with an encrypted disk with multi-core Banana Pi M3. Encryption/decryption performance is currently the bottleneck, so I'd like to know if encryption and decryption with dm-crypt can utilize multiple cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in recent kernels, dmcrypt requests can be parallelized. The [parallelization patches](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1304.1/01458.html) have been integrated into [4.0](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/dm-crypt.c?v=4.0), at a glance (4.0's `dm-crypt.c` includes `kthread.h`, previous versions didn't). Older versions had a single work queue for dmcrypt requests so different blocks couldn't be encrypted or decrypted in parallel (even on different devices, as far as I know).

However parallelization is not always a win. It takes some time to dispatch requests to a different CPU and collect results, so it's a win only if there are enough requests in parallel and you aren't waiting on a single block at a time. Typically you'd win if you have multiple applications accessing different files but not so much (or possibly even lose a little) when working with a single large file.

If you want better encryption performance, get something based on an ARMv8 processor, with AES acceleration, i.e. in practice a 64-bit CPU. Hardware crypto acceleration makes a real difference, far more than parallelization does at the best of times, and it helps for all workloads as long as CPU time is the bottleneck. Note that not all ARMv8-based CPUs have hardware crypto acceleration (it's sometimes left out to avoid running into crypto export/import regulations). But even without hardware crypto, running in 64-bit mode can be a measurable speedup.

It turns out that the Pi 3 doesn't have crypto extensions. The Banana Pi M64 might be right for you, since [it has crypto extensions](https://linux-sunxi.org/A64) (if I didn't get confused between the very similar SoC names). The Pi M64's SATA subsystem is on top of USB 2 though (like the M3), and this isn't as fast as the versions with a native SATA controller, so a Raspberry Pi 3 may be just as good if I/O turns out to be the bottleneck because the crypto doesn't saturate the CPU anyway.

Comment: Thank you, ARMv8 instructions is something I haven't considered. I'd prefer a SATA board as I don't have good experience with R-Pi + USB HDD, the disk doesn't seem to be very reliable in this setup. The boards I've reviewed have either SATA or ARMv8, but not both, I'll keep searching.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Be careful, there are sometimes power-related problems with those.

Comment: @phk Which ones do you mean? Boards with SATA, or more like ARMv8 boards with SATA?

Comment: @PetrPudlák I was thinking of the following: https://linux-sunxi.org/Lamobo_R1#Current_drawbacks Maybe the problems there can't be generalized but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: At the end I went for Raspberry Pi 3 and I don't regret at all, the HW crypto acceleration makes a _huge_ difference. The en/decryption speed used to be 3Mb/s on the older Pi model, on R-Pi3 it's more than 25Mb/s!

Comment: @PetrPudlák Do you know if the Pi3 is actually using the dedicated AES hardware instructions? I can't seem to find definitive information; several forum posts assert that the Pi 3 doesn't have these instructions so as not to run into crypto export restrictions. It could be faster at crypto because 64-bit mode it has more, bigger registers. Does `/proc/cpuinfo` list `aes`?

Comment: @Gilles In my case it shows features `half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32`, so doesn't include `aes`. Actually, the CPU is ARMv7, not v8, but still, the speed has increased dramatically (5-10x) compared to the older version of Pi.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Thank you! So no hardware AES, not even SHA. A Pi 3 does have an ARMv8 CPU even if you use it in 32-bit mode, but then I wouldn't expect much better crypto performance than a Pi 2. Or were you replacing a Pi 1? The Pi 1 did have a pretty slow CPU.